# Enable HTTPS connections?

Tags: https, apache-config

I don't knwo much about server maintainance and configuration, but i just started using one form mediatemple VE-Server...everything is fine and easy btu i dont get how can i enable the https connections...

if now i type **https:**//mysite.com/login.php it doesnt work (page not found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of tutorials out there for this. For example: http://tim.oreilly.com/pub/a/onlamp/2008/03/04/step-by-step-configuring-ssl-under-apache.html